# Can you connect UWP apps peer-to-peer?

Tags: c#-4.0, network-programming, uwp, windows-10-universal, p2p

I want to share data between to instances of the same UWP app, running on different devices.  The typical scenario would be phone-laptop.

I know can share data via a web-based service or some other mechanism, but I'm interested in knowing if it's possible to just connect them directly.

I'm not fussy on the type of network connectivity - e.g. via Bluetooth or local my local (home) WiFi.

Is it possible, and if so what would the approach be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a couple of options; if your scenario the devices are owned by the same user you can have a look at this post;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/communicate-with-a-remote-app-service